# How do I fix "sh: 1: title: not found" error in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, token, twitch

I want to make a twitch token generator for a discord bot, but when i run it, I get the error

```
sh: 1: title: not found
```

I think the part of the code that went wrong is

```
success = 0
fail = 0
created = 0

def count():
    while True:
        os.system(f'title S = {success}/ F = {fail} / C = {created}')
        time.sleep(1)
```

full source code [here](https://replit.com/@Unknown1789/twitch-token-gen#main.py)

Does anybody have any ideas? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is `title` a *program* to call or..? (Because [os.system](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-system-method/) is used to run shell commands and external programs.)

Comment: There's no shebang.  Add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in line 1

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system(f'title S = {success}/ F = {fail} / C = {created}')
```

Why are you trying to *execute* a string (which is what `os.system()` does) that you probably should just be printing out? Something like:

```
    print(f'title S = {success}/ F = {fail} / C = {created}')
```

Your shell is unlikely to respond well to that.

Comment: I'd appreciate it had you voted to close as "unlikely to help further readers" instead of answering.

Comment: @iBug, because I think it *may* help future readers. There are some questions that obviously don't meet that criteria but that's a call every SO'er has to make based on their own experience. You're free to do so if you wish but commenting that you would rather I'd done it differently makes about as much sense as me telling you "I'd appreciate it had you upvoted the question instead of commenting" :-) Which I'm *not* doing, let's make that clear.